# How to rename sudo?

Tags: command-line, sudo

Default command is:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I want to replace command (sudo) with the user name. For eg:

```
username apt-get update
```

Comment: What do you intend to achieve with this?

Comment: `alias username=sudo`

Comment: `sudo` isn't a user, it's a command...

Comment: @muru. Just for fun.

Comment: @Zanna I know it's a command. Is there anyway to change it.

Comment: To rename a command, use `alias`, as suggested by fkraiem

Comment: Eeven better: use `alias username='sudo '` (note the space at the end) to retain command completion for `sudo` on its alias.

Answer (score -5):

Use `alias username="sudo"` from the terminal to change it temporarily.

For a permanent alteration, add the same text to ~/.bashrc. You can use:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Or:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

to do this. If you try the vi route you will need to press `i` before entering the text, followed by the escape key, followed by `:wq` to save the file. If this doesn't work you probably need to update your version of vim, which you can do with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

If, on the other hand you want to change sudo contextually, so you instead just type in the name of the currently logged in user, try creating a "usernames.sh" file with this command:

```
vi usernames.sh
```

Or:

```
sudo vi usernames.sh
```

Depending on where you are creating it. Then enter this text:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases
alias $USER="sudo"
```

Make it executable using `chmod +x usernames.sh` then run this command:

```
./usernames.sh
```

To make it run every time you start the computer, type:

```
cp usernames.sh /etc/init.d
```

Followed by:

```
update-rc.d usernames.sh defaults
```

Again let me know if this works and if it's what you had in mind since, as I said, I do not have access to an Ubuntu terminal at the present time to test. If there are problems they can be fixed if I am made aware of them.

Comment: There's not reason to edit your bashrc with sudo, and `nano vi` makes no sense at all.

Comment: That. And he probably means his actual username and if logged in with another that username.

Comment: @Rinzwind what do you mean by "his actual username if logged in with another that username"?

Comment: He probably wants this `codered apt-get update` and when codegreen logs in `codegreen apt-get update` when codegreen has admin priviliges.

Comment: Someone may wish to check to make sure the new solution works as I do not have access to an Ubuntu terminal at present

Comment: You probably mean `alias $USER=sudo`, but this won't work in the `.bashrc` (or rather `.bash_aliases` btw) if not added with the actual username.

Comment: The OP is not here but my guess is that other users might find out about sudo and try to execute it so that with this change, it would have a different name. Otherwise, it doesn't seem to make sense but perhaps the OP can enlighten us on his ultimate intentions.